# How would Divine Health apply to a paladin that is a parasite?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, paladin

If an intelligent parasite becomes a paladin and attains the Divine Health feature, what happens? It would have to protect against hyperparasites, but what else does it affect in this context?

Comment: What sort of "intelligent parasite"? Are you using homebrew sources? Is that parasite published somewhere or created by you? It's kinda going to depend how exactly the race works.

Answer (score 2):

### “Intelligent Parasite” is not a playable race, so the rules don’t address this.

There is no officially published playable race that is an intelligent parasite, so the rules do not address this. A DM that permits a homebrew race that’s interact with the Divine Health feature would have to come up with a ruling for how it works.

Notably, one of the race backstory options for the Dhampir origin states:

> A parasite lives inside you. You indulge its hunger.

If you happen to select this Dhampir origin and the Paladin class, it seems to make a little sense to have your class invalidate your racial choice, so the natural ruling (in my opinion) would be for these features to not interact at all, but again, ask your DM.